# Any way to pass a variable into a django meta class?

Tags: python, django, attributes, leaflet, metaclass

I am working on a django app that lets the user create a point on a map. This map needs to be centered at a certain location for ease of use, and this location is variable. I am using a `LeafletWidget` to let the user create this point.

The map can be centered by changing the attributes of the `LeafletWidget`. Unfortunately this widget is defined inside a `Meta` class, and as far as I understand you cannot pass a variable into it. Here an example of what I would like to do, somehow passing the variable `center` into the `Meta` class. `center` is a tuple with latitude and longitude values. This example code does not work of course. I don't know if you can somehow pass a variable into a `Meta` class.

```
class PointModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta(center):
        model = PointModel
        fields = ['name', 'point']
        widgets = {'point': LeafletWidget(attrs={'settings_overrides': {'DEFAULT_CENTER': center} })}
```

My best bet was defining the `widgets` attribute in the `__init__` function, however `Meta` classes cannot access these attributes if I am correct. When I run this no widgets are used.

```
class PointModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PointModel
        fields = ['name', 'point']

    def __init__(self, center):
        super(PointModelForm, self).__init__()
        self.widgets = {'point': LeafletWidget(attrs={'settings_overrides': {'DEFAULT_CENTER': center} })}
```

Do you have any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the attrs of a widget with:

```
class PointModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PointModel
        fields = ['name', 'point']

    def __init__(self, *args, center=None, **kwargs):
        super(PointModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if center is not None:
            attrs = self.fields['point'].widget.attrs
            subattrs = attrs.setdefault('settings_overrides', {})
            subattrs['DEFAULT_CENTER'] = center
```

You can then construct a `PointModelForm` with:

```
PointModelForm(center=(55, 12))  # for GET request
PointModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES, center=(55, 12))  # for POST request
```

Comment: I had no idea you could define the attributes in such a way. Thank you so much for the helpful answer!